# Why is it not possible to embed $\mathbb{R}P^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

the title is more or less self-explanatory.

**Why is it not possible to embed the Real Projective Plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$ in to the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$?**

I stumbled upon the following example: Let $\mathbb{Z}_2$ act on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by reflections (f(x)=x,f(x)=-x). Then the quotient space $Q$ is a cone over $\mathbb{R}P^2$.
$Q$ is not a manifold. **How to prove this statement?**

I tried the following: Suppose $0$ would have a neighbourhood which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then by restricting this homeomorphism one could Embed the projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Which is not possible (by google). However I did not find out why.

Is there an algebraic invariant, which prohibits it and is easy to visualize?

Comment: wiki has a non-rigourious proof for that.

Comment: Wait wait wait, you can! What's Boyes' Surface!

Comment: @Alec: Boy's surface is **immersed** in $\mathbb {RP}^3$, not **embedded** .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg what's the difference (I am not saying they are the same, I just... it's a new area to me!)

Comment: An embedding $f:X\to Y$ can be thought of as an "exact" copy of $X$ that happens to live in $Y$. An immersion $g:X\to Z$, is does not have to be injective, which is where the self-intersections come in. Like the Klien bottle, it is also non-orientable, so to immerse it in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it must pass through itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Every codimension one closed submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$ is orientable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/864058/3217) but [$\mathbb{R}P^2$ is not orientable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/525616/3217) .

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$You have two questions:

1. Why does $\Reals\Proj^{2}$ not embed in $\Reals^{3}$? (Your title question, which Georges has answered.)
2. Why is $Q = \Reals^{3}/{\pm}$ not a manifold? (The motivating question in your post, which 1. answers indirectly.)

Here's an alternative take on 2.: The "link" of the vertex of $Q$ (i.e., the boundary of the image of a ball centered at the origin of $\Reals^{3}$) is $\Reals\Proj^{2}$ instead of $S^{2}$. If some neighborhood $U$ of the vertex of $Q$ were homeomorphic to $\Reals^{3}$, there would exist a closed ball $B$ centered at the origin of $\Reals^{3}$ whose image in $Q$ is (contractible and) contained in $U$. Following with a homeomorphism $\phi:U \to \Reals^{3}$ would give a contractible subset of $\Reals^{3}$ whose boundary is $\Reals\Proj^{2}$.

The same idea implies, for example, that a cone on a $2$-torus is not a manifold, even though a $2$-torus *does* embed in $\Reals^{3}$.